# Rate of a binary linear code given all code words have weight integer multiple of 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Supposed C is a linear binary code with the property that each code word is of Hamming weight n*4 (that is every word has a Hamming weight that is an integer multiple of 4). Show that the rate of C is at most 1/2.

I am stuck on this and mostly looking for a place to start - I know lots of properties for binary linear codes, but I can't seem to relate any of these properties directly to a bound for rate. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

1. Show that the code $C$ is *self-orthogonal*, $C\subseteq C^{\perp}$. Meaning that for all $u,v\in C$ you have $u\perp v$, or $\sum_i u_iv_i=0$.
2. Show that if the length of the code $C$ is $\ell$ and $\dim C=k$, then $\dim C^\perp=\ell-k$.

Comment: I have successfully proven to myself that the code is self-orthogonal (both by showing that I have even weighted, orthogonal rows of the generator matrix, and by the fact that the code in question is doubly even), but I am at a loss for how to show 2. 
Am I also trying to show that the code is a self dual? I know self-duals are required to be [2k,k] codes, so that would satisfy my requirement, but I don't know how to relate self-orthogonality to self-dual.

Comment: Good job getting step 1! In step 2 you don't need self-duality. Step 1 showed that $C\subseteq C^\perp$. Recall from linear algebra that a subspace never has a higher dimension than the superspace. So step 1 implies that $\dim C\le \dim C^\perp$. The result of step 2 is just linear algebra. If $G$ a generator matrix of $C$, i.e. of rank $k$, then the solution space of the homogeneous system $Gx^T=0$ has dimension $\ell-k$. Review the relevant parts from your linear algebra text (comes in handy at other places in a coding theory course as well).

Comment: Well that would explain part of my issue - I have never taken a formal linear algebra course (skipped it in undergraduate studies in favor of taking a discrete mathematics course). I do not have much knowledge of what is meant by subspace/superspace.
Thank you for the help though!